# Change colour in stacked plots, ggplot 2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to use palette colours for my stacked plot:

```
p <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
geom_bar(aes(fill = a, y = b, x= c), data = df, width = 0.7,
         position="stack", stat="identity") + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

I tried the following but it didn`t work:

```
p + scale_color_brewer(palette = "PuOr")
```

Futhermore I would like to plot a line showing the mean over the barplot. Maybe somebody has a Idea how to.

Comment: pls add `dput(head(df))` to Q.

Comment: structure(list(a = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 
2003), x = c(6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 6), y = c(1, 
258, 1, 3, 9, 11)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: what is `b`? as in your call to `aes` `y = b` This variable is not in your data frame, Possibly you mean `y = y`? similar issue with x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1) better to use geom_col than geom_bar for values you want the bar to represent, see the documentation

2) Used `factor(...)` to make continuous variables discrete

3) you code will be easier to read if you follow the order of arguments as set out in the documentation; although of course it does not matter what the order is.

4) updated to reflect request with mean for each x value

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003),
                 x = c(6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 6), 
                 y = c(1, 258, 1, 3, 9, 11))

#data frame for means
df_y_mean <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(y_mean = mean(y))


ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x = factor(x),  y = y, fill = factor(a)), width = 0.7) +
  geom_line(data = df_y_mean, aes(factor(x), y_mean, colour = "red"), group = 1, size = 1) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuOr", name = "Year") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Mean", label = FALSE)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Just one more question, what if I would like to get the mean per bar (so the line wouldnt be horzizontal)?

Comment: Just to confirm you want the mean for each instance of x? So there would be 3 means. How would you want to display the mean for each x value?

Comment: Yes I would like to plot each x mean as a one line. So that the line connects the three different means

Comment: Answer modified.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `fill` but using `scale_colour_brewer()`. Use `scale_fill_brewer()` to modify `fill`.

To draw a horizontal line add `geom_hline()` to your plot call.

```
p <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
       geom_bar(aes(fill = a, y = b, x= c), data = df, width = 0.7,
       position="stack", stat="identity") + 
       theme(legend.position="bottom") 

my.mean <- mean(df$b) ## can be any value, change as needed
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuOr") + geom_hline(my.mean)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I get the error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Comment: I would need to see the data you're trying to plot. Maybe run `head(df, 3)` just so we can see what you're trying to plot.